# To Create a Custom Web Part, for obtaining a dialog box after clicking  a Hyperlink

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Imagine; in a sharepoint site, We get to add Documents ,lists etc.A Hyperlink will be present, on clicking it we get a Dialog box which promts us to browse and add  docs.

Now I need to create a custom webpart ,which has a hyperlink onclicking it I need a Dialog box like (Add docs).I need that dialog box to be a default one and not a custom generated.
How do i approch this problem.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use [SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410058.aspx) method javascript Client object model to open web pages or hidden div elements in a dialog box

2) The upload documents page URL usually is webURL/_layouts/Upload.aspx?List={List Guid}&RootFolder=. An easy way to find out the url is to right click on the "Add document" link and to copy shortcut.